# Can nerdtree use two windows to show working directory and browse directory

Tags: vim, plugins, nerdtree

Are there any plugins that will open two windows in vim， one displaying the current working directory (the directory I'm editing) and another used to browse directory.

Answer (score 3):

What about

- `vim .` to start NERDTree for the current working directory
- `CTRL-W CTRL-V` to start a new window
- `CTRL-W CTRL-W` to flip over to the new window
- `NERDTree [otherdirectory]` to start browsing `[otherdirectory]`?

That gives me two independent NERDTree windows.

Comment: Why the recent downvote on a solution over 4 years old? It would be nice for the downvoter to explain.

Comment: Not sure who down-voted, but this worked for me... thanks!

Comment: This does not work here. All windows with NERDTree then just changes to the latest given directory.